# "because it is she that I have watered": not "her"?

Tags: emphasis

In the book The Little Prince, there’s

> because it is she that I have watered; because it is she that I have put under the glass globe

Why “she” instead of “her”?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. This Q is better asked on [ell.se].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which one is correct to say: "It's me" or "It's I"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10643/which-one-is-correct-to-say-its-me-or-its-i)

Answer (score 3):

One of those old rules of English grammar based on Latin grammar stated that 'nouns in apposition' (when we say *A is B*) must be in the same case. So it is strictly correct to say "It is I", though most people in everyday conversation would say "It's me".

The translator used a rather old-fashioned style, then, though as the flower (a rose, wasn't it?) is the *object* of the attentions it does seem odd to use *she* and not *her*.

Comment: Have you come across ""It is her that I ..." in prose?

Comment: +1 ... and see other similar questions already answered on this site, eg: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336595/has-the-use-of-the-subject-pronoun-after-the-verb-to-be-become-archaic

Comment: @  Kris.I  would  like  to  know  whether  she  or  her  is correct  in the sentence.I  think  she is  correct .

Comment: @Kris: Google returns 19 results for "it was she that I", and 11 results for "it was her that I." Usage isn't coming down strongly on either side.

Answer (score -2):

It does sound a bit strange.  I thought it was perhaps because of the French but in French we have:

> - ...puisque c'est elle que j'ai arrosée.  Puisque c'est elle que j'ai mise sous globe.

*Elle* in French is a pronoun that can be the subject (*she*) or the object of a verb (*her*).  Here it is unambiguously the obejct of *arroser* (water) and *mettre sous globe* (put under a glass globe).  There is nothing odd about the French sentence that could account for the translator's choice of *she* instead of *her*.  It's a perfectly neutral way of saying things. The use of stilted or overly poetic language and constructions is clearly not called for.  I would translate the passage as:

> - ...because it is her that I have watered; because it is her that I have put under the glass globe

Comment: No, 'she' is fine here. It's slightly poetic prose.

Comment: In the days of Shakespeare, I believe you used *she* after forms of the verb *to be*, no matter whether you were formal or informal. (He uses "It was she 3 times, and never "it was her".) I don't think was ever true in French (*c'est moi*). It has changed in English, but some people still follow this rule with formal language.