# "I too" versus "me too"

Tags: phrase-usage

I was talking to someone earlier today, and while trying to relate with them, I suddenly found myself trying to decide between "I too" and "me too". I can't quite grasp their differences.

As I understand it, "me too" is valid only on its own, in response to someone's statement.

> Person 1: I absolutely love that new album
>
> Person 2: Me too! Doesn't everyone?

Whereas, "I too" works (I believe) in both that scenario, as well as at *(is that wording correct?)* the beginning of a response phrase.

> Person 3: I too, enjoy the album you mentioned.

Regardless of whether I am right or not, can someone please explain the mechanics behind this?

Comment: 'Me too' is just an informal usage. To be strictly grammatical, Person 2 should have said 'I do too' or 'So do I', but that sounds a bit stilted in everyday chat.

Comment: Related: [I didn't realise it was him](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/121198/8019)

Comment: As a note: "I too" is rather formal in AE. My personal feeling is that "I too...." is actually used more frequently to be intentionally and amusingly overly formal or proper sounding. In every day usage it would never be used seriously.

Comment: @KateBunting To be strictly grammatical one could just say: 'Me too'!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In modern English, we don't use nominative case Subjects when there isn't a tensed verb in that clause.

> It is rare for [**him** to miss a class].
>
> *It is rare for [**he** to miss a class]. (ungrammatical)

The proform *too* can stand in for a tensed verb phrase. However, because it is not actually a verb and therefore has no tense, we cannot use a nominative Subject with it:

> - *I too! (ungrammatical)
> - Me too! (grammatical)

Answer (score 1):

'I too' definitely doesn't work where 'me too' does.  Think of 'I too' as replacing the words 'I also'. This will work for Person 3, but doesn't fit as Person 2's response.

> Person 3: I also enjoy the album you mentioned.
>
> Person 2: I also! (doesn't work) Doesn't everyone?

In addition, you would also place a comma after 'I' and before 'too'.

> I, too, enjoy the album you mentioned.